# How to make Dropdown List in ONSEN-UI?

Tags: cordova, drop-down-menu, onsen-ui

I am developing `phonegap` application and for this I want `Dropdown` Menu in my `ONSEN` page.
*How to achieve it?*
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `<ons-popover>` element as a dropdown. I made a simple example:

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/MYzVYb

To define a popover you use `<ons-template>` (or put it in a separate file).

```
<ons-template id="popover.html">
  <ons-popover cancelable direction="down">
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item ng-repeat="option in options" modifier="tappable">
        {{ option }}
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-popover>
</ons-template>
```

In a controller you can defined the scope:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('DropdownController', function($scope) {
  ons.ready(function() {
    ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {
      $scope.popover = popover;
    });
  });

  $scope.options = ['Load', 'Sync', 'Settings'];
});
```

This controller should be a parent to the popover so you should attach it to the body.

Then you can trigger the popover using `ngClick`:

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Dropdown example</div>
    <div class="right">
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="popover.show($event)"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
  </ons-toolbar>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Yeah....Its working...Thnx brother...Now how to get that selected value from the popover?...I mean in your example,I want to select 'Load' option,then how can we show that selected value?

Comment: What do you mean? I guess you want to perform some action when clicking on it so you can use `ng-click="someAction()"`.

Comment: the only reason why this work is because the controller is in the body:
if you put the controller in here ons-page it stop working. and of course you cant be changing the body controller every time you want to load a new page. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbPBxM

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is not good. It's because the popover creates an isolate scope. It's actually been fixed in the next release of Onsen UI so you can do `createPopover(page, scope)`.